# need to set header dynamically with the content

Tags: angular, polymer

i am using ag-grid-polymer and i want to wrap the content in the header.user can enter any text and that should fit in the header column size.now it is coming like ellipses.

```
  .ag-theme-material .ag-header-cell-label .ag-header-cell-text {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word }

.ag-theme-material .ag-header-cell-label {
  display: flex;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% -18px); }
```

tried with this.but it didn't work.thinking to customize with function .any help should be appreciated.

Comment: Example: if user enter header text  "Football team championship" it is coming like "Football Te....."but my requirement is it should come full text in that header.

Comment: could you add the code of how you have draw your grid or place in a stackblitz ?

Answer (score 0):

> Example: if user enter header text "Football team championship" it is coming like "Football Te....."but my requirement is it should come full text in that header.

The result that your are seeing is because of `text-overflow`.

The `text-overflow` CSS property sets how hidden overflow content is signaled to users. It can be `clipped`, display an `ellipsis` (' **…** '), or display a custom string.

Remove below from css for `.ag-theme-material .ag-header-cell-label .ag-header-cell-text`:

```
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

You can read more about [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) here.

**EDIT**: The problem is not with the text, you are getting complete text in HTML bindings, the `css` is deciding to show and add `...` based on the length of the text.

Comment: Can you give any function so that without overriding css I can handle this through logic.plunker link also should be helpful

Comment: Your CSS will always truncate your text no matter what function you use. The best way is to override your `css` properties by attaching another `css class` that overrides the above said `css` properties. Or you can increase the width of your cell-label and it would work as you expect. The problem is not with the text, you are getting complete text in HTML bindings, the css is deciding to show and add `...` based on the length of the text.

Comment: If I remove text-overflow and will add min-height will that helpful

Comment: i can't tell exactly since you do not have a working example here, but yes increasing the width should display the entire word